# jquery how can i collect matching elements?

Tags: jquery

if any one give me a suggession to collect matching elements using each?

this is i tried:

```
<ul>
<li class='options'></li>
<li></li>
<li class='options'></li>
<li></li>
<li class='options'></li>
<li class='options'></li>
</ul>​

var x = $();

x = (function(){
$.each($('li.options','ul'), function(i,e){
    return e;
})
    })()

    console.log(x)//i am getting undefined.
```

[here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scDhx/)

how can i collect the matching elements?

Comment: Can you define _matching elements_?

Comment: `var x = $("ul li.options")` perhaps?

Comment: What do you mean, you want a count of the li's? $('.options').length?

Comment: If you want to collect DOM Element objects, use `get` method `var x = $('li.options','ul').get()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because you have return only inside iterative each function, but not in outer anonymous function.
It should be something like this:

```
var x = (function(){
    var elements = [];
    $.each($('li.options','ul'), function(i,e){
        elements.push(e);
    })
    return elements;
})();
console.log(x);
```

Comment: Or `$("ul li.options").toArray()`.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery selector will itself return the matching elements as collection

```
 $('ul > li.options')
```

Thanks

Comment: i agree. but the thing is i am correcting the old style js document.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do it like this if your trying to get the options values. And if you would like to compare them you could simply put them in comparing array depending on what your final goal is (in not fully sure what you mean by matching in this case)

```
$('.options').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).html());
});
```

Comment: 1. `Console` should be `console` 2. for `li` elements `text/html` should be used, `val` should be used for form elements, 3. -1.